# Purpose of function export in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If we take a look at the following example:

```
# testing(){ echo hello;}
# testing
hello
# echo $(testing)
hello
# echo testing >script
# ./script
./script: line 1: testing: command not found
# source ./script
hello
# export -f testing
# ./script
hello
```

It turns out that a `bash` function needs to be exported only if you want to use it in a non-sourced script. I tried several levels of subshells, the behavior is the same. Can someone confirm this, because I find it contradictory with the claim that local variables do not exist in subshells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source ./script` does not create a subshell. The script is executed in the current shell. Nothing unexpected here.

However a command substitution like in `echo $(testing)` *does* create a subshell. If I get you right, you're surprised it works.

This is explained in [Bash Reference Manual, Command Execution Environment section](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment) [emphasis mine]:

> **Command substitution**, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands **are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment**, except that traps caught by the shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation.

So it's a documented exception to the claim that local variables do not exist in subshells.

Answer (score -1):

Functions become part of the process's environment by exporting them, just like variables. So to inherit them for subprocesses like a called script, they must be exported. Until it is not exported it is part of the shell's variables only.

Note: you can list the current environment with the `env` builtin command, and list the variables with `set`.

Note2: the `source` command does not create a subshell (subprocess), as others point it out also, so the `source script` works as you show it in the example. But the `./script` command creates the subshell so you need to export the function.